# I want to put extra text into R.array.****

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",0);
```

I want to put this extra text to R.array.**"this extra text"**

```
    String[] loveshayari=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.**value**);
    RecyclerView recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(loveshayari,getApplicationContext()));
}
```

}

[Supported image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr59I.png)

Answer (score 0):

No bro you cannot store and modify values during runtime and use later.

Solutions :

1. Use SharedPreference to store and retrieve data during runtime even after relaunch the app.
   For more details:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

2. Use Room or SqliteHelper to store and retrieve data in local database and use that data later which you want.
   For more details:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room